# How to only display last x values in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on some output formatting for while loops, and I cannot figure out how to only display the last x number of items. For example:

```
z = int(input("x value: "))
y = int(input("y value: "))
list_a = []
x = y - z #x is how many values i want to display
z = z - 1
while True :
    try :
        z = z + 1
        if z > y :
            break
    except ValueError:
        break
    list_a.append(z)
print(list_a)
```

I would only like it to display the last x values. How do I do that?

Comment: You are *building* the list in the first place, so you aren't displaying the "last" elements of anything. What list are you trying to build?

Comment: How about `list_a[-x:]`?

Comment: I think you just want `list_a = list(range(z, y+1))`.

Comment: The exception handler is useless: the code in `try` never raises `ValueError`.

Comment: @chepner I think that worked! thank you

Comment: @JonSG I tried that, but as chepner pointed out I am building the list so I think that makes it not work

Comment: @DYZ I see, I think I threw that in because I was getting an EOF error

Answer (score 0):

This function uses a list and how many items from the end of the list you want as arguments and returns those last items as a list.

```
def get_last_of_list(list, x):
    x = len(list) - x
    return list[x:]
```

Example:

```
list = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
print(get_last_of_list(list, 2))
```

Will print:

```
['Three', 'Four']
```

Comment: Would I be able to replace the '2' with a variable that is determined by inputs?

Comment: You can always try it and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, you can put any number for the second argument. If it is determined by input make sure you convert it to an integer before using it as an argument in the function.

Comment: @enzo ah, I tried it and it worked, although it gave me a weird, triangle shaped output.

Comment: x value: 10

y value: 16

    [10]

    [10, 11]

    [10, 11, 12]

    [12, 13]

    [14]

    [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

Comment: If you are using the function in a loop, it may be printing like that. Try printing the list only once, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use neagtive indexes

Example:

```
y=5 # use input here I am just using for example
z=2

x = y-z
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

print(list_a[-x:])
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't trying to access the last `x` elements of an existing list; you appear to be trying to *build* a list of integers between `z` and `y`, inclusive.

```
list_a = list(range(z, y+1))
```